# Mixing HTML and markdown-generated HTML in R Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny, markdown

I have a shiny site that uses a simple HTML file, a set of plotly tools, and a simple markdown-generated HTML file.

When I include the markdown-generated HTML file into the Shiny interface via includeHTML("doc.html"), the plotly tools become unresponsive (clicking on the tabpanel link does nothing).

The unresponsiveness of the plotly tabpanel exists only when I include the markdown-generated HTML file.

The site (with the unresponsive plotly 'tools' tabpanel) is hosted here: https://payneinstitute.shinyapps.io/test4jc/

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Will be hard to help without seeing the code in the `includeHTML`

Comment: Thank you for reaching out -- I no longer experience the problems after updating Markdown and Shiny